# Stadium Reverb Ambience

Tags: design, sound, ambience, reverb

I need to put this samba track into a stadium

obviously a single reverb instance won't do the trick (at least I've tried but it didn't - Space designer from Logic)
It sounds dirty and confused while everytime I go to a stadium for a Serie A football match I'm always amazed by the crystal clear texture of the choirs and the overall ambience .. it's all blurry but very nice sounding at the same time..

so I thought maybe multiple reverbs taking care of each ambience bit can work

but I'm not that expert .. so let's go social :)

any suggestions? tips?

you can have a listen here

[Sample1](https://soundcloud.com/ballpen/sample1)

Answer (score 2):

Convolution reverb would be your best bet here. Find an impulse response that is recorded inside a stadium and run the plugin via auxilary send so you don't wash out the initial sound source. Make sure to also EQ the reverb if needed, Space Designer comes with a built-in EQ but you can also use a typical channel EQ as well.

Comment: I tried with SpaceDesigner with its Soccer Stadium impulse on a bus send - tried to EQ it but it's nowhere near the real thing :)

Comment: You might need more tweaks than just EQ on it. Pre-delay and wet-dry levels are very important for getting the sound you want. Ideally the reverb plugin will be in an aux channel and 100% wet and then you can balance the wet/dry using faders (if you're not already doing it that way). You might put a delay plugin before the reverb on the aux channel to give you more delay/pre-delay control. Also it can help to EQ before *and* after the reverb, and don't underestimate compression before and/or after the reverb also as tools to shape the sound.

Comment: Yes, What Todd Said, plus I think you need more high end reverb with lots of feedback. Don't assume the presets will be right for your needs.

Comment: thanks for the insights fellas .. yeps .. been tweaking SD in various ways but Space Designer always sounds a bit crap to my ears.. at the same time I'd so love to learn more in detail how to re-construct ambiences properly ..  as you mentioned, I imagine it involves more than just a Reverb, EQ .. know any interesting tutorials, guides etc.. that explain this subject in depth? .. so far google didn't help much .. either scattered infos or basic stuff... I'm looking for something from the ground up in details..

Answer (score 0):

If it sounds crystal clear in a real stadium, that's probably because there is a speaker with the dry signal relatively close to you.  I also think it's probably much louder than the volume you are mixing at.

So to get the same effect, you'd have to turn up the volume of your speakers and then lower the (preferably convolution) reverb volume to make it more dry, until it sounds clear enough.

Since you probably want the same level of both clarity and ambiance at lower volumes, what you can then do is lower the speaker volume again and add parallel compression instead.

Comment: thanks Her .. when I said "crystal clear" I was referring to the people singing together .. so no speakers involved .. just pure vocal sounds traveling around the stadium .. as for the parallel I'm looking for an in depth tutorial on how to re-design spaces since I'm not a rev expert for such precise things..